# Persist UUID in PostgreSQL using Play Slick - java.sql.BatchUpdateException

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I've been playing around with Play and came upon a problem while trying to save some sample data into PostrgeSQL.

I'm aware that I can convert UUID to String and save it that way, but I can't get it to work with UUID.

The error I get:

> Error injecting constructor, java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into "COMPANIES" ("ID","NAME")  values (?,'Amazon') was aborted: ERROR: column "ID" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea

My dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.1.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.1"
```

Company case class:

```
case class Company(id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID, name: String)
```

Slick table definition:

```
val companies: TableQuery[Companies] = TableQuery[Companies]

class Companies(tag: Tag) extends Table[Company](tag, "COMPANIES") {
  override def * : ProvenShape[Company] = (id, name) <> (Company.tupled, Company.unapply)

  def id: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.SqlType("UUID"))
  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("NAME")
}
```

In logs I've noticed that UUID gets converted indeed into bytes:

```
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: insert into "COMPANIES" ("ID","NAME")  values (?,?)
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - /-------------+-----------\
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | 1           | 2         |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | Bytes       | String    |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - |-------------+-----------|
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | [B@17c2de51 | Amazon    |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | [B@6a4e93d5 | Google    |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | [B@69f81ed7 | Microsoft |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - \-------------+-----------/
```

I would really appreciate some help or hints.

Comment: Have you imported the slick driver for Postgres? `import dbConfig.profile.api._`

Comment: What an oversight from my part! Previously I was fiddling with H2 so I imported `import slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._` instead of PostgresProfile, the compiler did not complain and I forgot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the specific profile for your database system. In your case:

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
```

Although I would recommend injecting the configuration provider and then import that api. That way your code will work if you configure another database management system.

```
class DAO @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("DB_NAME_FROM_CONFIG") protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
                      (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {
  import profile.api._

  ...
}
```